# XCUITest-swift: Is it possible to fetch TableView Cell via value attribute?

Tags: swift, swiftui, automation, xcuitest

I have attached a debug description of the sample code

```
Element subtree:
 →Application, 0x2803763e0, pid: 10436, label: 'Settings'
    Window (Main), 0x2803764c0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {390.0, 844.0}}
      Other, 0x2803765a0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {390.0, 844.0}}
        Other, 0x280376680, {{0.0, 0.0}, {390.0, 844.0}}
          Other, 0x280376760, {{0.0, 0.0}, {390.0, 844.0}}
            Other, 0x280376840, {{0.0, 0.0}, {390.0, 844.0}}
              NavigationBar, 0x280376920, {{0.0, 47.0}, {390.0, 44.0}}, identifier: 'Customize Top Level Menu'
                Button, 0x280376a00, {{0.0, 47.0}, {67.0, 44.0}}, label: 'AssistiveTouch'
                StaticText, 0x280376ae0, {{89.0, 58.7}, {212.0, 20.3}}, label: 'Customize Top Level Menu'
              Other, 0x280376bc0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {390.0, 844.0}}
                Other, 0x280376ca0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {390.0, 844.0}}
                  Other, 0x280376d80, {{0.0, 0.0}, {390.0, 844.0}}
                    Other, 0x280376e60, {{0.0, 0.0}, {390.0, 844.0}}
                      Other, 0x280376f40, {{0.0, 0.0}, {390.0, 844.0}}
                        Other, 0x280377020, {{0.0, 0.0}, {390.0, 844.0}}
                          Table, 0x280377100, {{0.0, 0.0}, {390.0, 844.0}}
                            Other, 0x2803771e0, {{0.0, 91.0}, {390.0, 55.3}}, identifier: 'TAP AN ICON TO CHANGE:'
                              Other, 0x2803772c0, {{0.0, 91.0}, {390.0, 55.3}}, label: 'TAP AN ICON TO CHANGE:'
                            Cell, 0x2803773a0, {{0.0, 146.3}, {390.0, 389.0}}
                              Other, 0x280377480, {{0.0, 146.3}, {390.0, 0.3}}
                              Other, 0x280377560, {{16.0, 535.0}, {374.0, 0.3}}
                              Other, 0x280377640, {{19.7, 146.3}, {351.0, 351.0}}
                              Other, 0x280377720, {{63.3, 230.7}, {65.0, 65.0}}, label: 'Custom', value: Top left
                              Other, 0x280377800, {{63.3, 340.3}, {65.0, 65.0}}, label: 'Gestures', value: Middle left
```

Here we can see that, table cell has label as well as value attribute. I am able to access table cell via label attribute.

```
Eg- app.tables.otherElements["Custom"]
```

but can't access table cell via value ie. app.tables.otherElements["Top left"]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be possible to locate an element by value using `NSPredicate`. You can try something like this:
`app.tables.otherElements.matching(NSPredicate(format: "value MATCHES[cd] 'Top left'"))`
or
`app.tables.otherElements.matching(NSPredicate(format: "value CONTAINS[cd] 'Top left'"))`
`[cd]` is for `Case- and diacritic-insensitive lookups`, you can probably omit it. Official [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspredicate). I've tested this only with switches where the value is a number but I assume it should also  work for strings.